# Location of the Android SDK has not been set up in the preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

facing issue during installing android sdk ,i tried first with https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and then ADT-23.0.6.zip from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

can you help me out?

[image: not setup pref]

[image: all items installed]

Comment: You should really really USE Android Studio http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Comment: thanx,but i am already working with xamarin studio also

Comment: Click Open preference and follow the remaining steps.

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you update your ADT? 
Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software -> Add, Name it ADT and Location to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
2) Go to preferences-> Android -> Android preferences. Set the location of Android SDK.

Comment: Then go to preferences and set up the location of Android SDK.

Comment: click on SDK manager and please see if the latest version of Android SDK tools is installed.